# Uncaught Error: No module: ui.bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am trying to install bootstrap to the dependencies according to [this documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but I get `Uncaught Error: No module: ui.bootstrap`

*Files loaded by index.html:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
....

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

*app.js*

```
app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngProgress','ui.bootstrap']);
```

The documentation says all I need is:

- AngularJS (minimal version 1.0.4 or 1.1.2)
- Bootstrap CSS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing the script reference to the Angular UI Bootstrap script itself. You need to download it and make a reference to it.

For instance the latest version: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-0.6.0.min.js

All versions here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages

As you can see, the angular `ui.bootstrap` module is defined in that script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

only download the bootstraps css

you need to link the bootstrap js file, so you controller can get ui.bootstrap